# Gallery on Facebook Messenger (Node.js)

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

I'm making a chatbot for Facebook Messenger with Node.js. This bot has a gallery (image + button), and I have problems with the size of the images, it's possible to change the generic size of the pictures on the gallery? If not... Could be some similar effect of the messenger's gallery (image + button) to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's more like a header picture or thumbnail not for display a fullsize picture. This article has good explanation for image gallery. -> https://www.chatbot-academy.com/facebook-messenger-gallery/